# Error importing a component which links to an ECL stub

Tags: ecl, content-porter-2013

I am using Content Porter to export/import a component which links to an ECL stub component. When exporting and importing I have the Structure and Content dependencies checked (and no others). If I look in the export zip, I can see the stub component and the folders that contain it are included, however when I run the import, I get an error:

> 2015/02/24 13:14:59 <132> [Error]
>   Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.ImportExportException: Item
>   '/webdav/000%20Empty%20Master/Building%20Blocks/System/stubs/6B8/777/ecl%3A0-mm-185-dist-file.ecl'
>   cannot be imported because it is absent on import TCM and its content
>   was not exported to the package.

**UPDATE:** It seems to be a problem with Content Porter finding dependencies - as if I run the import twice from the same export package, the first time for the top level publication (000 Empty Master) which contains the stubs, and the second time for the other blueprint levels, it works OK.

Comment: I'm assuming the error you list here is coming from the Content Porter log, is there also something logged in the Tridion event log on the CM server around the same time?

Comment: No errors in the logs

Comment: I am facing the same problem, Do we have the solution or another way of solving it apart from what ray mentioned ! Even i don't see any issue in event log. But here is few of the errors from my log: `Item cannot be imported because it is absent on import TCM and its content was not exported to the package.` `The Item cannot be imported due to the fact that its dependency cannot be imported.`

Comment: I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 7):

The only option that we've found working is by *separately* exporting and importing the stubs from the parent publication before exporting and importing the other items.

Disclaimer: I don't know if this is the right way to do it, but as said, it seems to be the only option.